# Problem getting preview from Django-MarkItUp in Admin interface

Tags: django, markitup

I am working on a custom markup formatter for Django and I wanted to interface it with MarkItUp.

It is successfully being called when I save the field, which is of type MarkupField, but when I try to preview this field from the Admin interface using the default settings, all I get back in the preview box is plaintext.

I am using the MarkItUp version from here: http://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-markitup/src

Here are my settings:

```
MARKITUP_FILTER = ('util.wookie.formatter.wookie', {})
JQUERY_URL = 'js/lib/jquery.js'
```

In urls, I have the following line:

```
(r'^markitup/', include('markitup.urls')),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is something serving the assets from both the MARKITUP_MEDIA_URL the JQUERY_URL locations?

Comment: I looked at the GET's coming from my development server, and it appears that everything is being served. (I see requests for the images used by markitup, jquery, and "/markitup/..." pages and it returns with a 304 or 200). The actual markitup editor is loaded, it's just the preview window that is giving me grief.